# What can be a possible input for this program ?

Tags: c

I'd like your help with understand  what can be an input from a user to the following program that can make the output:`U%ae'$ffq' ong string`

```
int main(void) {
    int i=0;
    char j[22]="This is a long string", k[3];

    scanf("%2s ", k);
    sprintf(j, k);
    printf("%s", j);
    for (; i< 21; printf("%c", j[i++]))
        ;
    return 1;

}
```

I don't understand couple of things:

k can get only two chars from the user- Is this what `"%2s"` means, no? and then writes into the array pointed by j the content pointed by the array k, so `j` is not pointed to k, but if we'll `j[5]` we'll still get `i`. so  I don't understand how can we get this input whatsoever since the input would be chopped to two chars `j[0], j[1]` would be the two chars from the input and the rest of `j[i]` would be the original rest of "This is a long string".

Comment: What is your input to the program, i.e. what is `k` after the call to `scanf`?

Comment: Also, which output is wrong? The stand-alone `printf` or the loop printing single characters, or both?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `help with understand what can be an input` h/she wants reverse engineering.

Comment: k is a variable which used to store the input from the user, and then being copied to j. it doesn't have any special meaning or purpose.

Comment: FWIW, I did not witness this behaviour with VC2010 or gcc 4.1.2. The first three `char`s of `j` were changed (two new `char`s and terminating NULL), the rest remain unchanged.

Comment: I understand the purpose of `k`, but I would like to know its _value_, i.e. its contents. What is the input that creates the given output?

Comment: If `k` contains a `%` code, you will get Undefined Behavior....

Comment: @JoachimPileborg a series of chars. you can type what ever you want, it doesn't have any meaning, it should fill the condition that the output of the program would be as described.

Comment: `k` is like filled with `\0'.But, **length of output != number of printed char**. Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only guessing here, but the problem is probably with the loop. You do not check for the string terminator, but print all of the array regardless of if the string has ended or not.

If you change the loop to this:

```
for (; i < 22 && j[i] != '\0'; printf("%c", j[i++])) ;
```

You should get the expected output.

(Note: I also changed `21` to `22` which is the size of the array. You can of course do `i <= 21` as that is the same.)

**Edit:** Rereading the question after the comment from hmjd.

If the input as read by `scanf` contains a percentage (`'%'`) character the call to `sprintf` afterwards will try to parse it as a formatting code. If I test this program with the input `%d123`, then `k` will be `"%d"` as expected, but the resulting array `j` will be `"192795408\0long string"`.

Comment: I think he is asking why is the remainder of `j` modified after the `sprintf()`, which should change the first three `char`s of `j` only.

Comment: I can't change the code, the code is given to me and I need to answer the question I asked.

Comment: @hmjd You are probably right. Edited my answer to include a possible problem.

Comment: @Numerator You don't have to change the code, I have edited the answer to include a problem with the code you presented in your question.

Comment: +1, the example in the edit caused more than the first 3 `char`s to be modified.